# How to derive an optimal, continuous-time linear quadratic estimator from a Luenberger state observer?

Tags: control-theory, parameter-estimation, optimal-control, kalman-filter

How does one derive an optimal, continuous-time linear quadratic estimator from a Luenberger state observer?  I am aware of a Kalman filter, but I would like to see a derivation of an observer without the stochastic elements for learning purposes.  Specifically, given the system

\begin{align}
x^\prime &= Ax + Bu \\
x(0) &= x_0 \\
y &= Cx \\
\end{align}

we can design a Luenberger type of state observer with the equations

\begin{align}
\hat{x}^\prime &= A \hat{x} + Bu + L(y-C\hat{x})\\
\hat{x}(0) &= \hat{x}_0
\end{align}

where the gain $L$ must be chosen according to some criteria.  If we let the error be $e=x-\hat{x}$, we can find that

\begin{align}
e^\prime &= x^\prime - \hat{x}^\prime\\
&=...\\
&=(A-LC)e
\end{align}

Hence, we need the matrix $A-LC$ to be Hurwitz or $\Re(\lambda(A-LC)) < 0$.  This implies that the error goes to zero and $\hat{x}$ approaches $x$.  Now, it seems like there should be an optimization formulation to find an optimal gain, $L$, that appears similar to the equations for a continuous-time Kalman filter.  I don't know what that formulation is.  If I try a formulation such as

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\min\limits_{e,L} && \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^TQe + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \textrm{tr}(L^TRL)\\
\textrm{st} &&  e^\prime = (A-LC)e
\end{array}$$

the result seems off.  Here, the constraint is bilinear, between $e$ and $L$, so we can't get a quadratic objective with a linear constraint and therefore a linear system to solve for optimality.  What is the correct form of the optimization formulation?

Comment: Hi: could you give the name of a paper or a text that discusses what a Luenberger state observer is ? I'm a little familiar with Luenberger but not his state observer. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds There's a paper from 1971 titled "An Introduction to Observers" by Luenberger that gives a formal description.  For an easy presentation, Bemporad has a presentation from 2010 titled "State estimation and linear observers" with a series of slides that provides the set of equations that I use above.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check those out. It's much appreciated.

Comment: It was very easy to find both of those references. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the same way as for LQ optimal controller design.

Consider $$\dot{e} = A^\top e + C^\top u$$ with $u = -L^\top e$. The spectrum of $A^\top-C^\top L^\top$ is the same as for $A-LC$. Then you minimize the quadratic cost $$J = \int_0^\infty \left(e^\top(\tau) Q e(\tau) + u^\top(\tau) R u(\tau) \right)d\tau.$$

Here $u$ is your estimation error injection into the model's dynamics of the observer. However, since this injection is somewhat virtual, the term $u^\top R u$ does not represent the energy cost minimization as it does for LQ control. The role of $R$ is thus less intuitive.

Comment: I can confirm this works.  In case anyone else is trying this, the gain produced from the LQR equations will be `-inv(R)CP`.  This needs to be transposed to get the observer gains, `L=-PC'inv(R)` because we transposed the original equations.  I very much appreciate the help!  As a brief follow-up, both the choice of `Q` and `R` are nonintutive to me.  `Q` is a weight on an adjoint solution of the error equations.  `R` is a weight on the control that relates adjoint of the observer operator.  Any insight into their meaning without a stochastic argument?

Comment: $Q$ defines the penalty for the estimation error. A higher penalty implies faster convergence. You can also play with diagonal elements of $Q$ to put more penalty on some components of the estimation error vector $e$. And $R$ is introduced to have a well-posed problem; otherwise, $L$ tends to be infinite.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  As a point, if we used the original system for error, `e'=(A-LC)e`, I would very much agree.  However, here, we use the adjoint system, which appears necessarily different.  Say we just wanted to scale things for units, if we use `A`, we're scaling elements in the codomain of `A`.  Essentially, the scalings in the state equations.  Here, if we use the transpose, `A'`, then the scaling of `Q` appears to affect elements in the domain of `A`, or scalings in the state variables themselves.  How would you view the difference between `A` and `A'` when setting penalties?

Comment: It is a good point, but my discussion is mostly based on the cost function.